# Can't understand the possibility of overflow when resizing ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, resize

The quoted code snippet from the JDK 7 `java.util.ArrayList` class confuses me. I can't for the life of me understand how can it possibly result in overflow. The areas which I'm confused in are marked with `<--- what do they mean by this?`. Can someone please help me out in understanding the circumstances under which this logic might overflow? TIA.

```
public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    if (minCapacity > 0)
        ensureCapacityInternal(minCapacity);
}  

private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
    modCount++;
    // overflow-conscious code <--- what do they mean by this?
    if (minCapacity - elementData.length > 0)
        grow(minCapacity);
}

private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;

private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code <--- what do they mean by this?
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}

private static int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow <--- what do they mean by this?
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    return (minCapacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) ?
        Integer.MAX_VALUE :
        MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
}
```

EDIT: My main concern is: how can hugeCapacity ever receive a negative size?

Comment: It's not a "stack overflow" overflow if that is your concern with the comments in the Java code.  It is about the managed capacity of the internal array.

Comment: @jowierun: You are right, stack overflow is not my concern here. I'm pretty sure the comments speak of datatype overflow/capacity overflow. The new `new OutOfMemoryError()` in `hugeCapacity()` method is the one which has got me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OutOfMemoryError()` (in `ArrayList`) is thrown for 2 conditions:

1. The `minCapacity` is less that zero. That means that a memory array allocation cannot be created, i.e. `elementData` array size cannot be less that zero.
2. The capacity of the array has exceeeded the VM memory heap space. The VM cannot create memory (`grow()`) to allocate more object in the array.

Hence why `hugeCapacity()` ensures that memory is allocated safely.

---

`grow()` and `hugeCapacity()` is only used within `ensureCapacityInternal()`, so one can say that the `minCapacity < 0` is unecessary. I believe it's a safety check put in place, just to render the growing of array safe. Any discrepency, rather throw an error.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, but given that there already is a check for `capacity > 0` in the `public ensureCapacity` method, how can `minCapacity` be less than 0?

Comment: +1, thanks for the reply. I have been trying so hard (playing around with values) to ensure that the control goes in minCapacity < 0 block but can't think of *any* scenario wherein that can happen. Not sure why the check is in place...

Answer (score 2):

an overflow results when a calculated value is larger than the number of bytes allowed for its type.

After performing some operations on `oldCapacity` value is being assigned to `newCapacity`, if these operationf result into some value that does not fit into `int` then overflow will occur. I guess thats why this code is commented as overflow consious code.

Comment: OK, point taken. But why does `hugeCapacity()` method have to check for capacity < 0? What are the cases in which hugeCapacity will receive a negative value?

Comment: I have not gone through the complete code, sorry for that, but yes minCapacity can be less than zero. For example if some calculations were performed on minCapacity and the result was higher then it can for into minCapacity. So java will drop some of the higher order bits to make it fit into the int. While doing this, the sign bit might get turned on. thus making it a negative value. @sasuke

Comment: But shouldn't the public method `ensureCapacity` which checks for `size > 0` (as per the code posted in my question) filter out such cases?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this code may have at some point been modified to work with arrays where array.length is a `long`.  (Of course, that ain't regular Java ... as we know it.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the situation where `minCapacity < 0`. Suppose there are two long size ArrayLists, when you add one to another,  the `size + numNew` will overflow.

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
    size += numNew;
    return numNew != 0;
}
```

For example, the code below will throw an OutOfMemoryError.

```
int oneSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 16;
int twoSize = oneSize >> 1;
List<Byte> one = new ArrayList<>(oneSize);
for (int i = 0; i < oneSize; i++) {
    one.add((byte) 1);
}
List<Byte> two = new ArrayList<>(twoSize);
for (int i = 0; i < twoSize; i++) {
    two.add((byte) 2);
}

one.addAll(two);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's about the representations of the number. If Integer.MAX_VALUE adds one, it would be a negative number,-2147483648. So, if the array is big enough, we grow it again will cause `minCapacity` less than 0.